# How to create dictionaries of sets consisting of folder and files in os.directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I want to generate a dictionary of sets like the below example

```
{ "1" : ["IMG_0001", "IMG_0002","IMG_0003", "IMG_0004"] }
{ "2" : ["IMG_0020", "IMG_0021","IMG_0022", "IMG_0023"] }
{ "3" : ["IMG_0051", "IMG_0052","IMG_0053", "IMG_0054"] }
```

where 1,2,3 are the folder names and IMG_001,.. are the images names inside each folder

I have tried a for loop with os.walk('inside path name') and

```
import os, os.path
h={}


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r'Path_data_folders'):
#    print("subdir ",subdir)
#    print("dirs ",dirs)
#    print("file ",files)

    # simple version for working with CWD
    
    for file in files:
        for i in range(0,3):
            s=set()

            s.add(file)
  
            h[i]=s
            print(h[i])
```

Can anyone please help me how should I create a dictionary of folder names and create set of only those IMG files which are present in each folder. Appreciate your help. I am a new in python. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import os
h={}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Path_data_folders"):    
    for file in files:
        key, value = os.path.basename(subdir), file  #Get basefolder name & file name
        h.setdefault(key, []).append(value)          #Form DICT
print(h)
```

Note: If you need full path to folder name use `subdir`, This might be required because you might have duplicate sub folder

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for helping me out. 
This is GroundTruth
{'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png'],
 '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'],
 '3': ['IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png']}
This is clustering output
{'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png'],
 '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'],
 '3': ['IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png']}

How to do difference and generate accuracy. I thought of Rand Index (ARI)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have nested folders with images in them then this will work.
Otherwise, the key will have the relative path of the nested folders.

```
result = {subdir: files for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/your/directory")}
```